# Recommended deployment mode for Reactjs

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, packaging

My application is built on microservices architecture and heavily using spring boot.

we want to add an UI dashboard for our app and chose reactJs as we liked the framework. we are new to reactJs.

unlike backend server packagers, ReactJs has tonnes of tools for packaging such as webpack, gulp, babel, and so on

Coming from spring boot background, wondering if there is any recommended ways to package UI code that doesn't deviate much from existing spring boot?

Comment: I think Gulp is your best option, It is configuration is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully packed UI code into spring boot applications using [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/)

- build the UI with its own tools
- package these into a webjar
- in your spring boot app, add a maven dependency to the webjar
- add resource mappings to the ui content in the spring config

This works, but I dont use that approach any longer because

- you need to build/deploy the backend even for minor UI changes
- UI developer need to deal with backend configs and builds
- you use expensive server resources, just to serve static content

Instead

- build the UI with its own tools
- host them somewhere Amazon S3 or CDN

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I tried this approach. However managing dependency compatible version in webjar is really difficult. Most of the webjars are not available in central repository too.